# Summarise before collecting in arrow using strings for column names

Tags: r, dplyr, apache-arrow

Say I want to summarise a column in an `arrow` table prior to collecting (because the actual dataset is larger than memory). I could do something like this:

```r
arrow_table(mtcars) %>% 
  summarise(mean(mpg)) %>% 
  collect()

# A tibble: 1 × 1
#     `mean(mpg)`
#           <dbl>
#   1        20.1
```

Now, say I want to do this programmatically and the column name is provided as a string. In regular (i.e., non-`arrow`) `dplyr`, I could use `across` and `all_of` like this:

```r
foo_regular <- function(x){
  mtcars %>% 
    summarise(across(all_of(x), mean)) %>% 
    collect()
}

foo_regular("mpg")

#        mpg
# 1 20.09062
```

But how do I do this in `arrow`?

```r
foo_arrow <- function(x){
  arrow_table(mtcars) %>%
    summarise(across(all_of(x), mean)) %>%
    collect()
}

foo_arrow("mpg")

# Warning: Error in summarize_eval(names(exprs)[i], exprs[[i]], ctx, length(.data$group_by_vars) >  : 
# Expression across(all_of(x), mean) is not an aggregate expression or is not supported in Arrow; pulling data into R
# Error:
#   ! Problem while computing `..1 = across(all_of(x), mean)`.
# Caused by error in `across()`:
#   ! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
# ✖ Column `mpg` doesn't exist.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Clearly, performing the mean on that column is *possible* prior to collect in `arrow` as my first code chunk does this, but how do I specify column names with strings? As I say, the actual dataset is massive so pulling the data into R first isn't an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Edited to add: the advice below is no longer necessary; version 10.0.0 of arrow, which supports `across()` has now been released]

In the most recent released version of Arrow (9.0.0.1), `across()` is not yet implemented, but it has been implemented in the most recent development version, and so should be in the upcoming release (10.0.0).

For the moment, you can either install a nightly version of arrow via `arrow::install_arrow(nightly = TRUE)`, which will successfully run your code example, or manually specify the columns/functions to `summarise()` without using `across()`.

Comment: I see you contribute to arrow/R, thanks! Do you know of an expected timeline for release of 10? I know it depends on many things out of your control, but are you expected days, weeks, or months?

Comment: We do quarterly releases.  The next main project major release is scheduled for roughly 1 month from now, and then we send the R package to CRAN.